# How automatically convert xls to csv with google app scripts in gmail and send it

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, export-to-csv, xls

Every day I receive xls file with prices, but my online store accept only csv files.

May I automatically convert xls to csv with google app scripts in gmail and send it to another email

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly convert an XLS to a CSV via Apps Script, however you can indirectly convert it by utilizing the `GmailApp Service`, `Advanced Drive Service`, and `SpreadsheetApp service`.

Suggested Process:

1. Open the email with `GmailApp` [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)
2. Retrieve the attachment via 'message.getAttachments()' [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getattachments)
3. Insert the file into Drive via the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#reference),  [Insert Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) with the `convert` parameter set to true
4. Open that newly created spreadsheet, and get the data range with the [Spreadsheet App service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
5. Save that range as a CSV to drive [Reference with code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section-3-saving-a-selected-range-to-a-csv-file)
6. Attach that file to a new email and send it with [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)